# Is it possible to clone / install ROS2 dependencies packages as specified by rosdistro/iron/distribution.yaml?

Tags: ros2, rosdep

I have built `ros2 iron` and `gazebo fortress` under `debian bookworm`. Now I want to try `urdf_tutorial`

I have found `urdf_tutorial` and related packages under rosdistro/iron/distribution.yaml, what tools I can use to specify to install these packages?

I tried cloned the urdf_tutorial under `workspace/src`, but it still cannot resolve depedencies for urdf_launch which urdf_tutorial depends on?

Should I clone relied packages into `workspace/src` all by hand ?